# Trigger packet transmit for DPDK/DPAA2 from FPGA

Tags: fpga, dpdk

I want to transmit a small static UDP packet upon receiving a trigger signal from an FPGA by GPOI. This has to be done around 1 microsecond with low latency and no jitter. My setup consists of FPGA card is connected tot NXP processor via PCIe lane.

My current experimentation showed that even starting the transmit from the GPIO interrupt handler in the kernel typically exhibits too high a jitter to be useful for the application (about one microsecond should be doable). As I am not familiar with DPDK, I wanted to ask whether it can be of any help in this situation.

Can I use DPDK to do the following

1. Prepare the UDP payload in Buffer.
2. Push the buffer to DPAA2.
3. Poll periodically for the GPIO from FPGA over mmaped area on PCIe in DPDK application.
4. Trigger the transmit of buffer in DPAA2 (and not CPU DDR memory).

Question: instead of issuing the transmit DPDK `rte_eth_tx_burst` the FPGA shall directly interact with the networking hardware to queue the packet. Can DPDK on NXP do the same for my use case?

note: If DPDK is not going to help, I think I would need to map an IO portal of the DPAA2 management complex directly into the FPGA. But according to the documentation from NXP, they do not consider DPAA2 a public API (unlike USDPAA) and only support it through e.g. DPDK.

Comment: can you help us understand your query? Is your statement `you want to use DPDK to send static UDP payload from NXP CPU with DPAA2, but need help in setting the Trigger from FPGA to the soft CPU core on the FPGA? or the trigger will be sent from FPGA via interrupt/GPIO line attached to NXP CPU core?`. I am not an expert in FPGA, but one can load static ethernet frame to either SRAM or DRAM of FPGA and sent it out too. One will end up writing a wrapper layer to translate the interrupt to event to be processed by CPU core if you use DPDK, So please clarify your question.

Comment: Hi Vipin. My intention is to trigger sending the payload directly from the FPGA without involving the CPU for this by directly interacting with DPAA2 infrastructure. The setup of the buffer can be done on the CPU.So the question is, can I use DPDK to set up a queue and prepare a buffer but implement essentially `rte_eth_tx_burst` on the FPGA? If the answer is yes I would proceed with this, otherwise I would try to work with DPAA2 directly without using DPDK.

Comment: Hi mnmltype, thanks for the clarification as `intention is to send static UDP payload from DPAA2 engine and not the CPU (em500) where DPDK or Linux kernel runs`. So your current question `is there a mechanism to send the buffer from DPAA2 without CPU`. As far I remember on DPAA with help of frame and buffer manager you can do it as baremetal code. So no need of Linux or DPDK here. What is confusing is FPGA part on NXP and DPAA2. that is not clear to me.

Comment: Hi, the FPGA is connected as a PCIe device in my system. So it can directly interact with DPAA2 by memory mapped IO.

Comment: thanks for the clarifying with full details. I humbly request to edit your question as this was not clear. I can share the edit too.

Comment: I have added edit which reflects the current requirement. As mentioned in comments, if you plan to use DPDK on NXP-DPAA2, please ensure the following items 1. mempool is created from DPAA2 frame and buffer manager rather than DDR hugepage, 2. Do pktbuff_alloc and set refcnt to `0xffff` which allows to preserve the memory. 3. have to PCIe interrupt  of FPGA pinned specific core and ensure no other interrupt runs on it. 4. the core application should house infite loop to check the interrupt or event change for GPIO and trigger rte_tx_burst. I do not know of an API which can do tx directly.

Comment: are there any updates?

Comment: I am working on this but it is not finished yet. Will take another couple of weeks I guess. I modified some code in ./drivers/bus/fslmc/qbman/qbman_portal.c in dpdk and removed setting the verb word which triggers the package transmit from software into qbman of DPAA2 in valid-bit mode. Next I will try to write the verb byte directly from FPGA via PCIe into the Enqueue Command Ring of DPAA2. I will report back as soon as it works.